# How to stop the sound - Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have a sound looped, its a rect button, once the user presses the button the sound loops and plays. I want it so once the user has pressed the same button again, the sound stops playing.

This is the code

```
- (IBAction)threeSound:(id)sender; {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (threeAudio) [threeAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    threeAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    threeAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
    threeAudio.delegate = self;
    [threeAudio play];  

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pretty straight forward...

```
- (IBAction)threeSound:(id)sender; {
    if (threeAudio && threeAudio.playing) {
         [threeAudio stop];
         [threeAudio release];
         threeAudio = nil;
         return;
    }         
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"wav"];
    if (threeAudio) [threeAudio release];
    NSError *error = nil;
    threeAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    threeAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
    threeAudio.delegate = self;
    [threeAudio play];  

}
```

Comment: This code also assumes that threeSound is being called for both events.

Comment: He mentioned "pressed the same button again" so I think it's correct.

Comment: Sorry, I agree with you, just clarifying in case someone else comes along.  =)

Answer (score 0):

You should separate those two processes
into this

```
`- (void)initSound {
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"wav"];
NSError *error = nil;
    threeAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    threeAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
    threeAudio.delegate = self;
    [threeAudio prepareToPlay];
    [threeAudio play];
}

-(IBAction)threeSound:(id)sender:(UIButton *)sender{
    if (sender.selected) {
    [threeAudio pause];
    } else {
    threeAudio.currentTime = 0;     
        [threeAudio play];
    }
    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}`
```

Note that initSound needs to be called at some point, if you want to start the sound with the button only.. then add

```
if (!threeAudio) {
       [self initSound];
}
```

at the beggining of the IBAction

Thats my advice ;)

Comment: This makes the code more complicated, unless you're stopping/starting the sound from other places than just the button, in which case it would make easier code. But either way works.